# How to get the position of a widget in the screen (preferably in Offset)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to implement Match-The-Following. The approach I could come up with is that the `onPanStart` and `onPanEnd` to get the starting `Offset` and ending `Offset`. I also need to get the Offset of the widget on the screen to match.

Is there any method to get the local position of widget on the screen (Widget is a `Container`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

Set a key for the Widget:

```
Container(
           key: _key,
           color: Colors.red,
         ),
```

And get the position of the widget like this:

```
 final RenderBox renderBox = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
```

Comment: It works pretty well. Just one more doubt though, does it return the center of the Container?

Comment: @AbhayVAshokan I'm not quite sure. I would guess its the top left corner. If so you could still pretty easily calculate the center.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this extension I wrote (requires Dart 2.6):**

```
extension GlobalKeyExtension on GlobalKey {
  Rect? get globalPaintBounds {
    final renderObject = currentContext?.findRenderObject();
    final translation = renderObject?.getTransformTo(null).getTranslation();
    if (translation != null && renderObject?.paintBounds != null) {
      final offset = Offset(translation.x, translation.y);
      return renderObject!.paintBounds.shift(offset);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**Example how to use it:**

```
final yourKey = GlobalKey();

Container(
  key: yourKey,
  width: 100,
  height: 50,
)

void printWidgetPosition() {
  print('coordinates on screen: ${yourKey.globalPaintBounds}');
}
```